# Convert a MS Access 2003 Report into a MS Visual Basic 6.0 Form

Tags: ms-access, vb6

Im in the process of porting a MS Access 2003 application to MS VB 6.0

Consequently, there are a few reports in there, which I need to port too.

Now I haven't found anything in formtypes or google, but is it possible to make something very similar to MS Access reports as a form in MS VB 6.0 or, even better, directly import a form from a MS Access 2003 .mdb file?

Mind you though, whatever I'll come up with, needs to work on everything from win95 to win10

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no easy answer for this one.  You can't import from Access, and VB6 doesn't even have native reporting capabilities.  Your choices will be a 3rd party library/app (easiest, but most aren't free and vb6 is WAAAY old and not much support anymore) or build your own (can be done, but very ugly and very time consuming in VB6)  If you're not mandated to use VB6, I'd suggest going with .Net as there's at least some of the necessary reporting components already written for you.

Comment: Sadly I am mandated to work with VB6 as the code needs to be compat from Win95 upward and the existing solution this needs to be merged with is already a VB6 application. Company will probably not loose some of their win95 machines that cannot be upgraded period for another 10-15 years at least, and multiple versions of the giant software are not permitted.

Comment: Then I'd ask what your budget is for a reporting solution, or add 3-6 months to project completion to allow you time to build the reporting solution (not joking, I've done it, it can be done quicker sure, but: good, cheap, quick, choose any 2)

Comment: Im not entirely sure about how much time I will have for this, but I hazard a guess at most ill be allowed to spend about 2 more weeks on this, of which I will probably need a couple days to port the remainder of the functions other then the reports. Also probably no budget beyond "free"

Comment: Well, good luck then.  You can try building on the included DataReport, but it isn't quite up to snuff with the ease of report generation you're familiar with in Access.  The only time I had a budget, I used ActiveReports, but I don't even know if you can get that anymore, as they were bought out and are now selling a .Net version.

Comment: I guess :/ If you want to post some of those you suggested as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try building on the included DataReport, but it isn't quite up to snuff with the ease of report generation you're familiar with in Access. The only time I had a budget, I used ActiveReports, but I don't even know if you can get that anymore, as they were bought out and are now selling a .Net version.